# SelectionSort with bool - first value of array appearing as whole tab

Tags: c++, boolean, selection-sort

im trying to write SelectionSort with bool.

```
void ss( int tab[], int n )
{
    bool flag;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        int min = tab[ i ];
        for( int j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
        {
            if( min > tab[ j ] )
            {
                flag = true;
                tab[ j ] = min;
            }
            if( flag == true )
            {
                int temp = tab[ i ];
                tab[ i ] = min;
                tab[ j ] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that when i put tab with values: 5 4 3 8 7 9 i receive tab with values: 5 5 5 5 5 5

Where do i make mistake? How this SelectionSort should like to be working properly?

Answer (score 2):

Try that code:

```
void selectionSort(int array[], int size)
{
   int startScan, minIndex, minValue;

   for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
   {
      minIndex = startScan;
      minValue = array[startScan];
      for(int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
       {
       if (array[index] < minValue)
         {
          minValue = array[index];
          minIndex = index;
         }
       }
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
        array[startScan] = minValue;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two large problems with your inner loop. First:

```
    for( int j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
    {
        if( min > tab[ j ] )
        {
            flag = true;
            tab[ j ] = min;
        }
```

So if the first element is the largest element, we just overwrote all of our elements with it? The idea is that we want to keep track of which index is the smallest. Not overwrite anything yet.

Secondly:

```
        if( flag == true )
        {
            int temp = tab[ i ];
            tab[ i ] = min;
            tab[ j ] = temp;
        }
```

This isn't actually a swap. You're `tab[j]` gets `tab[i]`, but `tab[i]` gets `min`... which is actually what it was before. You need to assign it to `tab[j]`.

Ultimately, this is not the correct algorithm. Selection Sort involves only doing one single swap operation per outer loop. We are **select**-ing the right spot for each element, and sticking it there.